# Get Authentication to the Email in Magento

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, magento, authentication

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

In my shopping site if any user creates an account,then i(automatically) have to send a authentication link to his/her email.when he/she click that link then only have to create account.

How can i do this one ?

I'm using Magento CE1.7.0.2

Comment: Please don't give down vote Its very Important to me

Answer (score 1):

There are already build in functionality provide by magento just go throw this step and you can find your solution.

1) Login to Admin…

2) Goto System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration (under Customers) -> Create New Account Options

3) Change “Require Emails Confirmation” to YES

4) Save, create account to test it out

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I am going to check this.